# When will apple's swift officially include open-source swift-algorithms?

Tags: swift, algorithm

Not only "swift-algorithms" but also "swift-collections" which is announced yesterday are so amazing library I think.

I wonder why apple didn't include that libraries in official swift.

Maybe you who will answer to me absolutely don't know too.
If you don't know, could you tell me if developer teams of each of library is different with developer team of official swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're both not in the swift standard library (yet) because they haven't passed the Swift Evolution process. This is explained in the [Swift Algorithms announcement](https://swift.org/blog/swift-algorithms/):

> It’s our ambition for the standard library to include a rich, pragmatic set of generic algorithms. We think the Algorithms package can help realize this goal by serving as a low-friction venue to build out new families of related algorithms—giving us an opportunity to iteratively explore the problem space and learn how different algorithms connect and interact—before graduating them into the standard library.